# Mongoose/ express how to retrieve only the values of the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to node.js and want to do the following thing.

Write a query to fetch the annotation(array values) key from mongoDb and pass this array values [only ] as an argument to the second query.

Here is my code

```
   // create the carousel based on the associated stills using keyword annotations
function findAssociatedArchivalStills(carousels, taskCb){
   async.waterfall([
// 1st query
 function findAssociatedAnnotations(archiveId, taskCb) {
      Archive.findAnnotations(archiveId, function onResult(err,annotations){
         console.log(annotations);
         taskCb(err,annotations);
     }); 
     },
 // 2nd query
  function findAssociatedStills(annotations,taskCb) {
    Still.findAssociatedStills(annotations,function onResult(err,stills){

        taskCb(err,stills);
    });
    },
  function buildCarousel(stills,taskCb) {
    return taskCb(null, new Carousel({
        title: 'Related Stills',
        items: stills,
      })); 
  },
], function onFinish(err) {
      taskCb(null, carousels);
    });
  },

// done building the associated Episodes carousel
], function onFinish(err, carousels) {
    handleResponse(err, res, carousels);
});
```

});

The methods are defined as follows

```
1st query definition in model

schema.statics.findAnnotations = function findAnnotations(archiveId, cb) {
this.findOne()
  .where('_id', types.ObjectId(archiveId))
  .select({'keywords':1, '_id':0})
  .exec(cb);
};

2nd query definition in model

schema.statics.findAssociatedStills = function          
findAssociatedStills(Annotations, cb) {  
this.find()
    .where({$text: { $search:Annotations}},{score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
    .sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
    .limit(2)
    .exec(cb);
};
```

> THE PROBLEM IS

When I ran the 1st query , it is returning following 
    { keywords:
    [ 'IRELAND',
     'ELECTIONS',
     'PARTY_POLITICAL_BROADCASTS',
     'FINE_GAEL' ] }

But the input to the next query should be only the values such as 
'IRELAND',      'ELECTIONS',      'PARTY_POLITICAL_BROADCASTS',      'FINE_GAEL'

How to filter from the result only the values of the array without key

I know what will be the query in MongoDb

that is as follows

```
db.archives.episodes.find({_id:ObjectId("577cd9558786332020aff74c")},       {keywords:1, _id:0}).forEach( function(x) { print(x.keywords); } );
```

Is it good to filter it in the query or is it right way to filter in the returned script.

Please advice.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're using series, not waterfall. And your *archiveId* cannot be set in the first function. You need to setup it before async.waterfall.

Here's the right syntax (with waterfall) :

```
function findAssociatedArchivalStills(carousels, masterCallback){
    var archiveId = 'yourArchiveId';
    async.waterfall([
        // 1st query
        function findAssociatedAnnotations(taskCallback) {
            Archive.findAnnotations(archiveId, taskCallback);
        },
        // 2nd query
        function findAssociatedStills(annotations, taskCallback) {
            Still.findAssociatedStills(annotations,taskCallback);
        },
        function buildCarousel(stills, taskCallback) {
            return taskCallback(null, new Carousel({
                title: 'Related Stills',
                items: stills
            }));
        }
    ], function onFinish(err) {
        if (err){
            return masterCallback(err);
        }
        masterCallback(null, carousels);
    });
}
```

**Documentation :** http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall

**PS :** Always use different names for your function's callback and your async functions callbacks.